# Spaces for which invariance of domain holds

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Suppose $X$ is a topological space such that if $A$ and $B$ are homeomorphic open subsets of $X^n$ and $X^m$ then $n=m$, what can be said about $X$?

From a point-set point of view there doesn't seem to be much that can be said about $X$, for example invariance of domain fails for $\Bbb Q$, the Cantor space and finite discrete spaces, so by knowing that it holds for $X$ we can't conclude much about separation properties or compactness of $X$, however all of the counterexamples I know are totally disconnected so there might be some hope as far as connectedness is concerned.

From an algebraic topology point of view invariance of domain might give some more information on, say, homology of $X$, is that the case? More generally what can we say about $X$ if invariance of domain holds for it?

Comment: The usual argument is essentially about the "local homology" at a point, $H_*(X, X -\{x\})$; on a manifold this is concentrated in degree $n$, and you conclude. There are things called homology manifolds defined by this property. But you should be able to say something in the generality of simplicial complexes.

Comment: I doubt that you will find a reasonable answer. Here are some connected counterexamples: $X = \mathbb{R}^\infty$ = countable infinite product of copies of $\mathbb{R}$, $X = Q$ = Hilbert cube = countable infinite product of copies  $[0,1]$. These spaces have the property $X^n \approx X$ for all $n$.

Comment: The problem is complicated by the following oberservation: Let $X = P + \mathbb{R}$, where $P$ is a one-point space and $+$ denotes disjoint union. Then $X^n, X^m$ always have homeomorphic open subsets (e.g. the components $P^n, P^m$), but if $n \ne m$, then there *exist* open subsets which are not homeomorphic (e.g. $\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m$).